# Getting 'AJAX Control Toolkit is undefined' when setting the CombineScripts="true"

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am getting **AJAX Control Toolkit is undefined** error when I have the CombineScripts="true" on the ToolkitScriptManager:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="false" ScriptMode="Release"
            LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" runat="server" CombineScripts="true">
            <CompositeScript>
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JavaScript/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JavaScript/Custom.js" />
                </Scripts>
            </CompositeScript>
        </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

But when I set the CombineScripts to false everything seems to work. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bug in ajax toolkit.

See this [link](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=15245) about the bug.

And this [site](http://forums.asp.net/p/1120906/2284787.aspx) has an explanation of a work around.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i have changed the CombineScripts attribut of ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager from true to false(CombineScripts ="false").

This works for me